# Payload becomes empty whenever it reaches the backend Wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

This is the code generated in Integration Studio. I'm hitting an API through my production endpoint. I'm converting the payload from XML to JSON, and I can see the payload successfully converted in the logs. However, whenever it reaches the backend, it becomes null.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/props" name="props_api" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json" template-type="freemarker">
                <format>{
    "name": "${payload.root.user.name}",
    "description": "${payload.root.user.description}"
}</format>      
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//root/user/name"/>
                    <arg evaluator="xml" expression="//root/user/description"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="application/json"/>
            
            <log level="full"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:8000/drinks/">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>-1</progressionFactor>
                            <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </address>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <send/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Here's the payload:

```
<root>
    <user>
        <name>s</name>
        <description>dd</description>
    </user>
</root>
```

The payload is successfully converted from XML to JSON, as seen in the logs:

```
{
    "name": "s",
    "description": "dd"
}
```

However, whenever it reaches the backend, it becomes null. Here's the error log:

```
[2023-02-26 18:13:21,282]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:props_api} To: /props, MessageID: urn:uuid:e5b8eb0f-85d0-4150-a284-1292b6c902be, correlation_id: e5b8eb0f-85d0-4150-a284-1292b6c902be, Direction: request, Payload: {
    "name": "s",
    "description":"dd"
}
[2023-02-26 18:13:21,282]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:props_api} To: /props, MessageID: urn:uuid:e5b8eb0f-85d0-4150-a284-1292b6c902be, correlation_id: e5b8eb0f-85d0-4150-a284-1292b6c902be, Direction: request, Payload: {
    "name": "s",
    "description": "dd"
}
[2023-02-26 18:13:21,306] ERROR {TargetHandler} - HTTP protocol violation : Not a valid protocol version: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" For : 127.0.0.1:8000 org.apache.http.ProtocolException: Not
```

Comment: i checked in backend payload is empty,reponse error is generating from backend only

Comment: Can you enable wire logs in MI and verify? https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer-and-observe/logs/configuring_log4j_properties/#wire-logs-and-header-logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an HTTP Endpoint rather than an address endpoint.

```xml
<endpoint>
  <http method="post" uri-template="http://127.0.0.1:8000/drinks">
      <suspendOnFailure>
          <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
          <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
      </suspendOnFailure>
      <markForSuspension>
          <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
      </markForSuspension>
  </http>
</endpoint>
```

If that doesn't work, enable the Wirelogs as Sanoj mentioned and share the logs.